# IS the given mail is good for follow up with HR - How can I improve it

Tags: interviewing, human-resources, email, follow-up

This ism my mail

> I have been interviewed at comopmayName for Mobile application
>   developer. This is just follow up mail.
>
> My skills are: A, B, C Reason for change: Financial and professional
>   growth.
>
> Looking forward to hearing back from you.
>   Regards,

How can I improve it?

Comment: What is your goal with the mail?

Comment: goal is to tell them like, you didn't call me after taking interview.. I am the suitable candidate for your position.

Comment: How long ago were you interviewed and when did they tell you to expect an answer?

Comment: @morsor - I have interviewd on 08March,

Comment: And did they at that time state an expected time frame for the conclusion of the hiring process?

Comment: @morsor - They said after one week they would call probably..

Comment: If you are reminding them that you interviewed with them I would say "you" or "your company" and so on instead of "company name (the name of the company)." And also remind them when that took place (e.g. 9 Mar). You don't need to remind them of your skills; that should be on your resume which you sent to them already in your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that's the wrong approach to take.  Instead, you should consider thanking for their time and if you think of any relevant additional information you didn't say during the interview, add that.

Something along these lines:

> Thank you for the opportunity to interview for position of (position) with you on (date of interview).  I appreciate the opportunity to meet with (peoples in the interview) and feel I am a good fit for the role because (specific skills here).
>
> OPTIONAL: (One thing that I neglected to mention during the interview was my experience with xxx, I feel this may be a good fit for the team)
>
> I look forward to hearing from you in due course
>
> Regards,
>
> r15